# How to show a address from gmap in c#?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I use Gmap in my project, and I want to show a address .

I tried to use BingMap, Yahoo, OpenStreet and googleMap. but I cant't show address.
I wrote this code:

```
private void gMapControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

                PointLatLng myPoint= gMapControl1.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y);
// GetAddress is my Method
                var addresses = GetAddress(myPoint);

                // Display Address
                if (addresses != null)
                    richTextBox1.Text = addresses[0];
                else
                    richTextBox1.Text = "Unable To Load Address";

            }

// this is my method

 List<string> GetAddress(PointLatLng point)
        {
            List<Placemark> placemarks = null;
            gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
            var statusCode = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap.GetPlacemarks(point, out placemarks);
            if (statusCode == GeoCoderStatusCode.G_GEO_SUCCESS && placemarks != null)
            {
                List<String> addresses = new List<string>();
                foreach (var placemark in placemarks)
                {
                    addresses.Add(placemark.Address);
                }
                return addresses;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

it's every time write in richTextBox (GoogleMapProvider):
"Unable To Load Address"

Comment: You'll need to examine your `GetAddress()` with the debugger. What is the `statusCode` and has `placemarks` been populated?

Comment: when I use GmapProvider.GoogleMap.GetPlaceMarks i dont have any Exemption . it's just every time null. but when I use Open Street Map and bing and etc... this line has error: – var statusCode = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap.GetPlacemarks(point, out placemarks); . can you  write a simple code that works right?

Comment: Have you accounted for the possibility that the coordinate does not have an address? Have you tried other known coordinates? At this point, this looks like a data problem rather than a code problem.

Comment: yes, I tried to use other PointLatLng. Is it possible about .net? or vs version ?! i use .net freamwork 4 in vs 2017 . I will try to use another vs. Can you display an address? maybe it's about Gmap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps requires the provision of a personal key, which is impossible to obtain in some countries, such as Iran, due to sanctions. It is recommended to use Open Street, which is a completely free service.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample code here

using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;

// init
gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
gMapControl1.SetPositionByKeywords("New York, USA"); 
gMapControl1.Zoom = 10;  

// GPS point
double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(txtLatitude.Text);
double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(txtLongitude.Text);

// GPS coord convert GMap.NET PointLatLng object
PointLatLng point = new PointLatLng(latitude, longitude);

// coord convert Addr using GMap.NET library.
GeoCoderStatusCode status;
Placemark? address = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetPlacemark(point, out status);

// Converted address 
if (status == GeoCoderStatusCode.G_GEO_SUCCESS && address.HasValue)
{
  txtAddress.Text = address.Value.Address;
}
else
{
  txtAddress.Text = "Not found Address.";
}
```